# Taking the expectation that involves vector of both constant and random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I have a $p \times 1$ vector $\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_1 \\ \boldsymbol{X}_2 \end{bmatrix}$ made of $q \times 1$ vector $\boldsymbol{x}_1$ whose values are known and $(p - q) \times 1$ random vector $\boldsymbol{X}_2$. I also have a diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{W} = \text{diag} \{ W^{-1}_1, \dots, W^{-1}_p \}$ whose entries are random variables. I need to find the following expectation
$$E \left \{ \left( \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_1 \\ \boldsymbol{X}_2 \end{bmatrix} - \boldsymbol{a} \right)^\top \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{W}^{-1} \boldsymbol{B}^\top \left( \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_1 \\ \boldsymbol{X}_2 \end{bmatrix} - \boldsymbol{a} \right) \right \},$$
where the $p \times 1$ vector $\boldsymbol{a}$ and the $p \times p$ matrix $\boldsymbol{B}$ are fixed. So far, I have applied the law of total expectation, that is, conditional on the entries of $\boldsymbol{W}$ first, we have

$$\sum_{w_1} \dots\sum_{w_p} E \left \{ \left( \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_1 \\ \boldsymbol{X}_2 \end{bmatrix} - \boldsymbol{a} \right)^\top \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{W}^{-1} \boldsymbol{B}^\top \left( \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_1 \\ \boldsymbol{X}_2 \end{bmatrix} - \boldsymbol{a} \right) \middle| W_1 = w_1, \dots, W_p = w_p \right \} \times P \left( W_1 = w_1, \dots, W_p = w_p \right), $$

but this looks so cumbersome. I think I need help with taking this expectation, and hopefully, there is a more compact way to represent it. I happen to know the expected value of each diagonal entry in $\boldsymbol{W}$, so I am trying to see how those values can appear. Please help me if you can. Thank you so much!

Comment: what's the relation between the rv in $W$ and $X_2$?

Comment: I don't think they have a particular relationship. They are two separate random variables I believe.

Comment: can we assume they are independent? or at least uncorrelated?